# Pyserial - is it possible to set two different stop bit settings for asynchronous serial communication

Tags: linux, pyserial

I'm trying to write an application in pyserial to talk to an external device (a Casio graphics calculator) which according to its manual uses 9600bps asynchronous serial with no flow control, no parity and 8 bits, but for the stop bit values it specifies 3 stop bits for sending and 2 stop bits for receiving.  The manual makes no mention of start bit length.

First, does anyone know how to specify two different stop bit values using pyserial, and secondly can you actually specify a stop bit length of 3?  The only options that pyserial has are 1, 1.5 and 2 bits.

I've so far managed to send single characters from my Linux laptop to the graphics calculator (setting either 1 or 2 stop bits seemed to work) but getting characters back from the graphics calculator isn't working (I have tested both the cable and port and they should work), so I'm guessing the stop bit setting could be an issue.  If anyone knows where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting problem (and well-described, thanks and welcome on StackOverflow). When you talk to the device with 2 stop bits configured, can you tell us what kind of output you're getting when you are 1) expecting a reply back from the device and 2) continuously reading byte per byte from the serial port (with a read-timeout configured)? It's possible the device uses 2 stop bits even when sending (some crappy manuals are out there...). And if not, it's likely that pyserial will (if configured for reading and writing 2 stop bits) ignore the extra stop bit and consider a full package received.

Comment: Cheers!  I'm getting no output from the calculator when it's outputting data.  I *should* be receiving a byte of value 0x15 from the calculator when I get it to send data, but the computer receives nothing.  I checked this with all three stop bit options but still to no avail.

Comment: Hmm... sometimes when debugging serial applications, I first use other tools. If memory serves, I once used [SerialMon](http://serialmon.com/) under Windows to figure out the entire communication protocol of a serial device. Perhaps tools like these, can help? Some really spit out **all the bytes**, including stopbits and whatnot.